# TV series with pull out phone screens and pink/purple space ships

Tags: story-identification, tv

I’m looking for a TV show where an alien race comes to Earth and sets up big purple/pink cylindrical or cone shaped spaceships in various cities around the world. The Aliens are not hostile but actually created peace and eliminated hunger on Earth.

- I believe the aliens had some human features and were wise and calm
- the main actor had a phone with a pull out screen
- I believe the main actor worked for or with the aliens
- I believe that in the last episode some humans and aliens go into some kind of pods and perhaps leave Earth?
- one of the space ships was located in a major US city. Maybe Washington DC or another East Coast city

Could someone please tell me what TV series this is? I have been searching everywhere and cannot find it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you remember when you may have watched it? What year? what channel? Etc.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This sounds a lot like [***Earth: Final Conflict***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0123816/) "created" by Gene Roddenberry (1997 - 2002)

[image]

> Early in the 21st century, a race of aliens, the Taelons (often referred to as "The Companions"), travel to Earth and take up residence in limited numbers. The Taelons possess highly advanced technologies, many of which they share with humanity, seemingly out of generosity and good will. **As a result of these advances, disease, war and pollution are nearly eliminated within three years of their arrival**. Despite this, some question whether the Taelons' motives are as benevolent as they appear, and a resistance movement forms to halt the Taelons' ever growing influence on humanity.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth:_Final_Conflict)</sup>

---

> Police Captain William Boone [Kevin Kilner] is asked to join the security team of Companion Da'an of the Taelon, an alien race that came to earth three years ago.

Taelon Shuttle / Spaceship

[image]

Taelon Mothership

[image]

Phone /Link type device

[image]

Taelon Embassy in Washington DC

[image]

Comment: Note that "created by Gene Roddenberry" means "created by Majel Barrett using enough notes and ideas from Gene after he passed away that they felt justified putting his name on it". I'd still love to know [how close it was to his original vision](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/68824/22502) for the show.

Comment: From my reading (a long time ago) not very...kinda like *Andromeda*

Comment: I'm not sure he even had a quantifiable *vision* just a broad set of ideas.

Comment: I never really got into the show, but I've always listed after one of those phones. With today's current generation of phones where the selling point is how big your screen is (along with how hard it is to fit in your pocket, and how easy they are to break when they fall out of said pocket). Forget that, I want those devices from *Earth Final Conflict* with the foldable screen.

Comment: @Simba I just assumed it was a *rollable* screen and we can't be far off now.

Comment: @Paulie_D - yeah, rollable. That was the word I was looking for. Either way, the manufacturers have been teasing us with the idea for at least a decade (and this show was longer ago than that), but it still isn't showing any signs of actually being turned into a real product.

Comment: They'll roll them out and holographic screens (per Tony Stark) will become a thing... *sigh!*

Comment: Hi guys thank you so much! This is definitely what I was looking for! When I finally found out what serie it was I went straight to YouTube and binge watched 4 episodes :) And yes, the roll out phone screens are crazy but I would love to have one so much